# Removing decimals from the TextBos while loading

Tags: javascript

```
obj[i]['Weight'] = parseFloat("0");
obj[i]['Height'] = parseFloat("0");
obj[i]['Temperature'] = parseFloat(0,10);
```

// This does not work...

```
obj[i]['Weight'] = parseInt(0,10);
obj[i]['Height'] = parseInt(0,10);
obj[i]['Temperature'] = parseInt(0,10);
```

// This too does not work...

My Input Value is 0, but when i show it... gives me 0.0 {Strange}.. So i did these and yet it shows 0.0

Comment: Define *does not work*? `parseInt(0,10)` gives correctly `0`. Although in this case, using `parseInt` is unnecessary. What do you mean by *removing decimals* anyway?

Comment: @Felix Kling: When i parseInt my value... it shows 0.0... why?

Comment: What is your value (input)? What is the desired output?

Comment: Don't know. `parseInt("124.42", 10)` gives me `124`. How about some more information, like which browser you are using etc.

Comment: @Felix Kling, i am not using browser... i am using JS for a Mobile Development.... is there any other way...

Comment: What is the type of the field? Could it be hmtl5 type="number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you say, `parseInt` does not work for you, then you can use [`Math.floor` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).

If this doesn't work either, maybe simple string manipulation helps:

```
val = val.substr(0, val.indexOf('.'));
```